# Building MySQL as non-root and with another MySQL already running

Tags: mysql, unix, bioinformatics, hpc

I need to use a bioinformatics tool that uses MySQL. The tool is called SyMap. When I try to run SyMap, it tells me there's a MySQL server already running so I should either shut it down or point SyMap to another server. Since I work on an HPC that allows me limited permissions, I cannot shutdown the MySQL server. So I've been trying to build my own local MySQL server. With zero knowledge about MySQL, this has been frustrating.

I tried to follow [this](http://www.thedance.net/~roth/TECHBLOG/localMySQL.html) guide to build MySQL as a non-root user with the addition of the flag MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3307 to the cmake command to have the local server run on a different port than the original's (3306). Whenever I get to the step where I have to execute mysql_install_db, it says:

```
2015-10-31 20:52:02 [WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please
consider switching to mysqld --initialize 2015-10-31 20:52:02 [ERROR] 
Child process: /home/rajeha/software/mysql/bin/mysqldterminated
prematurely with errno= 32 2015-10-31 20:52:02 [ERROR]   Failed to
execute /home/rajeha/software/mysql/bin/mysqld --bootstrap
--datadir=/home/rajeha/software/mysql/data --lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql --lc-messages=en_US
-- server log begin -- 2015-11-01T01:52:02.964453Z 0 [Warning] --bootstrap is deprecated. Please consider using --initialize instead 2015-11-01T01:52:02.969334Z 0 [ERROR] Invalid old_passwords mode: 1.
Valid values are 2 and 0

2015-11-01T01:52:02.969376Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting


-- server log end --
```

I also tried to run the `./bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql` command, but I still get the error that old_passwords is equal to 1.

If I try to run the server with mysql_safe, it says:

```
 *./bin/mysqld_safe: line 130: /var/log/mysqld.log: Permission denied ./bin/mysqld_safe: line 164: /var/log/mysqld.log: Permission denied
151031 20:53:12 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
 /home/rajeha/software/mysql/the.pid ended ./bin/mysqld_safe: line 130:
 /var/log/mysqld.log: Permission denied*
```

This is because it's trying to access /var/log/ which I cannot write onto. I probably have to change the config file that tells mysql to access this directory, and that also specifies the value of old_passwrods, but I don't know where to find it.

I would appreciate your help. 
Thanks.

Comment: you're running your own mysql, but trying to log to the original mysql install's log directory, which will NOT be accessible. you need to change ALL paths in your own install to places where whatever user you're running it under have the rights to.

Comment: Can you not just load the database into the existing MYSQL Server. One MYSQL Server can run many individual databases!

Comment: Thanks for the replies but could you include information on how to actually do these things? It may be natural to you but I'm still a nub.

Comment: I am using this post for my install, good so far:
http://superuser.com/questions/209203/how-can-i-install-mysql-on-centos-without-being-root-su

Comment: I tried following martin's instructions but it gave me an error at the fourth step "socket not a variable." I'm guessing with the new mysql, it's somewhat different. Please let me know if you have a solution since I haven't been able to solve this problem yet.